# pseudo class content not showing properly

Tags: html, css, accordion

Hi I've created a radio button accordion using css and html5, the problem I'm having is with the pseudo class for the section element it won't show it's content properly e.g content: '1' and content: '3' for their section panels. I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/mJdpjm) could someone see if they can get the numbers to be at the bottom of the panel and showing all corresponding numbers to show. I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/)

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/mJdpjm)

```
&:nth-child(1):after { content: '1'; } // doesn't show
&:nth-child(2):after { content: '2'; } // can't get it to line up
&:nth-child(3):after { content: '3'; } // doesn't show
&:nth-child(4):after { content: '4'; } // can't get it to line up
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `<label>` elements which are considered children of the `<section>` element and add towards the count.

So to compensate for the extra label element, change your child selector to the even numbers.

```
&:nth-child(2):after { content: '1'; }
&:nth-child(4):after { content: '2'; }
&:nth-child(6):after { content: '3'; }
&:nth-child(8):after { content: '4'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `nth-of-type()` is what you're looking for, rather than `nth-child()`.

```
.accordion section:nth-of-type(1):after {
  content: '1';
}
.accordion section:nth-of-type(2):after {
  content: '2';
}
.accordion section:nth-of-type(3):after {
  content: '3';
}
.accordion section:nth-of-type(4):after {
  content: '4';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0jc8s1q7/

Comment: Great article  - [The Difference Between :nth-child and :nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it would be something like

```
&:nth-child(2):after { content: '1'; }
&:nth-child(4):after { content: '2'; }
&:nth-child(6):after { content: '3'; }
&:nth-child(8):after { content: '4'; }
```

To compensate the extra label elements you have

Answer (score 1):

As @Liquidchrome pointed out you have other elements that are also children of the `.accordion` element.

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <input><!-- 1 -->
    <section><!-- 2 -->
    <input><!-- 3 -->
    <section><!-- 4 -->
    <input><!-- 5 -->
    <section><!-- 6 -->
    <input><!-- 7 -->
    <section><!-- 8 -->
</div>
```

An alternative to `:nth-child()` is [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). Try this:

```css
&:nth-of-type(1):after { content: '1'; }
&:nth-of-type(2):after { content: '2'; }
&:nth-of-type(3):after { content: '3'; }
&:nth-of-type(4):after { content: '4'; }
```

Comment: True I didn't see that, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't inspect my markup properly